Tracking links in mailings redirect to login screen
Since I updated CiviCRM to 5.72.1 (from 5.69) and Wordpress to 6.5.3, the links in my Mosaico mailings (tracking enabled) redirect to the Wordpress login screen (for logged out users. Links work fine when logged in).
I just don't know how to troubleshoot this. I suppose it must be some messed-up permissions, although I didn't change anything permissions-wise, and it worked perfectly in 5.69.
I see nothing in ConfigAndLog when testing the links.
Any ideas ? Thanks for any help.

Alright nevermind, I found the problem : it was my Wordpress extension Authorizer that was blocking any non logged-in access to CiviCRM.
Solved now.

Great, would you mark your question as answered / solved pleas?

You mean by accepting the answer ? I can only do that in 14 hours. Or should I add a [SOLVED] tag in the title ?

Yes I meant accepting the answer - feel free to do that any time ^^
